# How to configure scheduled azure webjob to run one instance?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I deployed a continuos Azure WebJob with one function triggered by TimerTrigger with CRON set to run every 2 minutes.

```
public async void ProcessScheduledNotifications([TimerTrigger("%Api.Settings.Crontab%", RunOnStartup = false, UseMonitor = false)]
            TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
        {
```

However, my code calls external API and it may take more than 2 minutes to finish. I found that even when one instance is running, the next instance is triggered after 10 minutes.

It there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

TimerTrigger uses the Singleton feature of the WebJobs SDK to ensure that only a single instance of your triggered function is running at any given time.you can use [Singleton] attribute on your functions.The [Singleton] attribute will restrict a function to only run one at a time across all instances, but do be aware that if you're on a Consumption Plan then you'll be charged for the runtime of any instance waiting for another instance to complete, which could significantly increase your costs .

```
[Singleton]
public async void ProcessScheduledNotifications([TimerTrigger("%Api.Settings.Crontab%", RunOnStartup = false, UseMonitor = false)]
            TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
        {
```

Comment: I think it means that having two app services, only one of them will run, but every scheduled run will be ran on this instance, even when previous is not finished.

Comment: you can read more about singleton and different available options . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#singleton-attribute

Comment: other options will be to set the function state in db and when function start you will check the function state and if it's already running then don't execute the code .