# How to run a task on only one web app instance in Azure?

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

Currently, I have a web app built using Python Flask and I have multiple tasks that I run on separate threads. Some of these tasks like a scheduler are tasks that I want to have running only on one instance or container in Azure. I would like to keep them inside my web app but in case I need to scale the number of instances I would like to have control over the number of instances that run these tasks.

Comment: please provide a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code or the approach you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

> use a distributed lock mechanism to coordinate this task across multiple instances. The idea is to create a lock that is shared between all instances of your web app.

- Use a distributed lock mechanism to coordinate this task across multiple instances. The idea is to create a lock that is shared between all instances of your web app.

Create a lock in your code using the chosen distributed lock service. Here's an example using Redis in Python with the `redis-py` library.

```py
import redis

# Connect to your Azure Redis Cache instance
redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host='your-redis-hostname.redis.cache.windows.net',
                                 port=6380,
                                 password='your-redis-access-key',
                                 ssl=True)

# Attempt to acquire the lock
lock = redis_client.lock('your-lock-name', blocking_timeout=1)
if lock.acquire():
    try:
        # Your task logic goes here
        print("Running the task on this instance.")
    finally:
        lock.release()  # Release the lock when done
else:
    print("Another instance is already running the task.")
```

- Configure the webapp to connect with the same Azure Redis Cache or your chosen distributed lock service.
- Each instance will attempt to acquire the lock, but only one will succeed, and the others will skip the task.

You can check with the **Singleton** feature of the WebJobs SDK also as a second approach. This feature ensures that only a single instance of your triggered function is running at any given time. Check this link to [configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383046/how-to-configure-scheduled-azure-webjob-to-run-one-instance).

- Use a container orchestration platform like Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) or Azure Container Service (ACS) to manage and scale your containers. With this approach, you have fine-grained control over how many containers run and where they run.